# Why Minipar in Gate runs forever?

Tags: gate

I'm using Win7 x64 system. 
I pointed MiniparBinaryFile to the exe file in gate/plugin/parser-minipar and MiniparDataDir to the data folder under the extracted minipar-0.5-windows32.

Gate launches to run the minipar but there is no more activity after launched. I have to kill the minipar-windows32.exe process.

What is the right way to use it?

cheers

Matt

----Update----

Thanks for Ian's suggestion, here is a cut of a VisualVM dump, Hope it's the correct part:

```
 
"ApplicationViewer1" prio=2 tid=0x000000000c0ad000 nid=0x1fb8 runnable [0x000000000f39e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    - locked  (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)
    - locked  (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at gate.util.BomStrippingInputStreamReader.stripBomIfPresent(BomStrippingInputStreamReader.java:93)
    at gate.util.BomStrippingInputStreamReader.(BomStrippingInputStreamReader.java:78)
    at gate.util.BomStrippingInputStreamReader.(BomStrippingInputStreamReader.java:45)
    at minipar.Minipar.runMinipar(Minipar.java:276)
    at minipar.Minipar.execute(Minipar.java:518)
    at gate.util.Benchmark.executeWithBenchmarking(Benchmark.java:291)
    at gate.creole.ConditionalSerialController.runComponent(ConditionalSerialController.java:154)
    at gate.creole.SerialController.executeImpl(SerialController.java:153)
    at gate.creole.ConditionalSerialAnalyserController.executeImpl(ConditionalSerialAnalyserController.java:129)
    at gate.creole.AbstractController.execute(AbstractController.java:75)
    at gate.util.Benchmark.executeWithBenchmarking(Benchmark.java:291)
    at gate.gui.SerialControllerEditor$RunAction$1.run(SerialControllerEditor.java:1619)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

=====update 2======

thanks the active development society, I installed the new version(Snapshot 4586) in a few hours.

Now it works!

however, I encountered another small problem.
gate reports error when processing the following sentence "Batten disease (also known as Spielmeyer-Vogt-Sjögren-Batten disease ) is a rare, fatal autosomal recessive neurodegenerative disorder that begins in childhood." (a wiki article)
In the Annotation view, I see the minipar annotated the sentence untill the uncommen character ö. 
So, is there a way to skip these?

In Messages Tab, it reprots:

```
gate.util.InvalidOffsetException
    at gate.annotation.AnnotationSetImpl.getNodes(AnnotationSetImpl.java:773)
    at gate.annotation.AnnotationSetImpl.add(AnnotationSetImpl.java:802)
    at minipar.Minipar.runMinipar(Minipar.java:419)
    at minipar.Minipar.execute(Minipar.java:527)
    at gate.util.Benchmark.executeWithBenchmarking(Benchmark.java:291)
    at gate.creole.ConditionalSerialController.runComponent(ConditionalSerialController.java:154)
    at gate.creole.SerialController.executeImpl(SerialController.java:153)
    at gate.creole.ConditionalSerialAnalyserController.executeImpl(ConditionalSerialAnalyserController.java:129)
    at gate.creole.AbstractController.execute(AbstractController.java:75)
    at gate.util.Benchmark.executeWithBenchmarking(Benchmark.java:291)
    at gate.gui.SerialControllerEditor$RunAction$1.run(SerialControllerEditor.java:1619)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
gate.creole.ExecutionException: gate.util.InvalidOffsetException
    at minipar.Minipar.runMinipar(Minipar.java:491)
    at minipar.Minipar.execute(Minipar.java:527)
    at gate.util.Benchmark.executeWithBenchmarking(Benchmark.java:291)
    at gate.creole.ConditionalSerialController.runComponent(ConditionalSerialController.java:154)
    at gate.creole.SerialController.executeImpl(SerialController.java:153)
    at gate.creole.ConditionalSerialAnalyserController.executeImpl(ConditionalSerialAnalyserController.java:129)
    at gate.creole.AbstractController.execute(AbstractController.java:75)
    at gate.util.Benchmark.executeWithBenchmarking(Benchmark.java:291)
    at gate.gui.SerialControllerEditor$RunAction$1.run(SerialControllerEditor.java:1619)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: gate.util.InvalidOffsetException
    at gate.annotation.AnnotationSetImpl.getNodes(AnnotationSetImpl.java:773)
    at gate.annotation.AnnotationSetImpl.add(AnnotationSetImpl.java:802)
    at minipar.Minipar.runMinipar(Minipar.java:419)
    ... 9 more
gate.creole.ExecutionException: Document doesn't have sentence annotations. please run tokenizer, sentence splitter and then Minipar
    at minipar.Minipar.saveGateSentences(Minipar.java:194)
    at minipar.Minipar.execute(Minipar.java:525)
    at gate.util.Benchmark.executeWithBenchmarking(Benchmark.java:291)
    at gate.creole.ConditionalSerialController.runComponent(ConditionalSerialController.java:154)
    at gate.creole.SerialController.executeImpl(SerialController.java:153)
    at gate.creole.ConditionalSerialAnalyserController.executeImpl(ConditionalSerialAnalyserController.java:129)
    at gate.creole.AbstractController.execute(AbstractController.java:75)
    at gate.util.Benchmark.executeWithBenchmarking(Benchmark.java:291)
    at gate.gui.SerialControllerEditor$RunAction$1.run(SerialControllerEditor.java:1619)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks again!

Comment: That should be correct, but I don't have any experience of running it on Windows.  Could you try capturing a thread dump using [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/threads.html) and edit the question to include the relevant portion of the trace for whichever thread is blocked inside `minipar.Minipar.execute()`?

Comment: Thx Ian, but I'm running everything from Gate developer GUI, not from Java code, can I still use Java VisualVM?  I have no experience with that.

Comment: yes, you can use jvisualvm to get a thread dump of the running GATE Developer. It should give you a list of available java processes to connect to, hopefully it'll be obvious which one you need.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to isolate the problem and it is indeed a bug, which should now be fixed in the latest subversion revision.

Comment: Just seen your latest edit, can I suggest that you move that into a new question as it's unrelated to the original (now solved) problem.

Comment: @IanRoberts Yes, that's right. please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598773/gate-how-to-let-minipar-play-with-special-characters-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in the Minipar wrapper PR, attempting to read from the external minipar process's "error stream" in the wrong thread.  This should be fixed in subversion ([revision 16615](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/16615/)) and is now in the [nightly build](http://jenkins.gate.ac.uk/job/GATE-Nightly/).

Comment: Thank you, Ian!  When can I expect the next nightly build?  and what will be the smallest build number that contains this bug-fix?  Nice weekend!

Comment: @Matt it builds around 2am UK time, check the [recent changes](http://jenkins.gate.ac.uk/job/GATE-Nightly/changes) list to see when rev 16615 appears. It should be build4586.